# Waiting period between rebounds and total time unitl an error is logged

Tags: flowground

I understood that through a rebound the processing can be repeated max. 10 times until an error is really logged.
But how long is the waiting period between the individual rebounds and how long is the total time between the first and the last attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time for waiting between rebound processing doubles with every iteration until a maximum of 10 minutes.
The wait time for the first iteration is 15 seconds.
The number of iterations is limited to 20.

[image]